# How to Clear Textfield and get back Focus to same Textfield controller on its own OnChange event in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, onchange

I have one Textfield controller in Flutter App and i want to Clear that Textfield and refocus in it after passing the value of that Textfield on its own OnChange event of that Textfield.

Actually in my app I want to scan continuously QR-Codes using external device i.e. QR-Code Scanner which is connected to the our android device. Then I want to display that each and every new scanned value to one label and update that value again after scan new QR-Code.

Anyone can help me to achieve it in Flutter ?

Comment: I hope you share your try and problem to give a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, because you just need to set the text back to empty on change.

```
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  TextField(
    controller: _textEditingController,
    onChanged: (value)=> _textEditingController.text = '',
  )
```

Is it this you wanted? let me know if it is not what you want.

Comment: Thnx for comment, this solution just clears textfield but not get focus back to it again.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the required feature, but I am not really happy with the approach, I would love to be corrected somehow. But you can definitely understand what needs to be done.

```
var _currentFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
var _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _currentFieldFocusNode,
  controller: _textEditingController,
  onFieldSubmitted: (newValue) async {
  setState(
    () {
      //do anything with new value
      _textEditingController.clear();
    },
  );
  await Future.delayed(
          Duration(milliseconds: 200))
      .then((value) => FocusScope.of(context)
          .requestFocus(
              _currentFieldFocusNode));
  },
),
```